# Oozie handling sensitive parameters (secrets)

Tags: hive, credentials, oozie

By default, Oozie will log any parameter. How can I prevent this behavior for sensitive parameters like passwords?

I know that some services directly can read from a file like [how can i provide password to SQOOP through OOZIE to connect to MS-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646645/how-can-i-provide-password-to-sqoop-through-oozie-to-connect-to-ms-sql) but I need to pass it as a variable to Hive.

Comment: Just musing: stuff the data in a text file, stuff the file in a custom JAR _(just a special ZIP after all)_ with a static method that retrieves the data, `add jar` in your Hive session _(unless blocked by Sentry/Ranger)_, invoke the method from SQL _(unless etc)_ cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38309083/5162372

Comment: Or use `aes_decrypt()` from SQL with a hard-coded pwd _(or sthg dependent on context e.g. hash of ISO date + hard-coded salt, to make it harder to crack from the outside)_